# SQL sample query (Is my answer correct?)

Tags: sql

Tables:

- `Classes (class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement)`
- `Ships (name, class, launched)`
- `Outcome (ship, battle, result)`

Question:

> Find for each class the number of ships of that class that sunk in battle.

My answer:

```
  SELECT ships.class, COUNT(*)
  FROM ships, outcome
  WHERE ships.name = outcomes.ship AND outcome.result = 'sunk'
  GROUP BY ships.class
```

Answer with join:

```
  SELECT class, COUNT(*)
  from ships
  inner join outcomes
  on name = ship 
  where outcome.result = 'sunk'
  group by class
```

Answer given in sample booklet:

```
  SELECT classes.class, COUNT(*)
  FROM classes, ships, outcomes
  WHERE classes.class = ships.class AND ship = name AND result = 'sunk'
  GROUP BY classes.class;
```

What I don't get is why did they have to include the `classes` table, isn't my query sufficient? I'm doing the same thing but not joining on the `classes` table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is this "Sample Booklet" you are reading that has SQL Queries with syntax that is 20 years out of date?

Comment: Your query is correct but can be improved upon by joining your tables

Comment: @RBarryYoung Dunno I got sample questions online. These are some slides by a TA..Hasn't mentioned the date.

Comment: @DanBracuk Thank you, will look at the join.

Comment: @DanBracuk I updated the question with join. Is that still correct?

Comment: Your updated query will yield same results as previous one. So your both queries are correctm

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The only real difference is that if there is a Class with no ships, the provided answer will include a row for it, where as your query would not.</strike>

Oops, sorry, I misread the sample answer initially.  There is no real difference between them.

---

It's also worth noting that this syntax:

```
SELECT classes.class, COUNT(*)
FROM classes, ships, outcomes
WHERE classes.class = ships.class AND ship = name AND result = 'sunk'
GROUP BY classes.class;
```

is archaic and deprecated.  This is the preferred modern syntax:

```
SELECT classes.class, COUNT(*)
FROM classes
INNER JOIN ships    ON classes.class = ships.class
INNER JOIN outcomes ON outcomes.ship = ships.name
WHERE  outcomes.result = 'sunk'
GROUP BY classes.class;
```

Comment: Meaning, the (old-fashioned) equi-join syntax (`WHERE tableA.fk = tableB.pk`) always performs an `OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: @stakx No, the old syntax would perform an inner join if `=` was used or an outer join if `=*` or `*=` was used.

Comment: @stakx Oops, I see what you meant.  No my initial answer is incorrect.  I will correct...

Comment: I  had initially misread the sample answer in the old syntax.  Ironically, I got it right when I re-conjugated it into modern syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Most simple answer...

```
SELECT class,
SUM(CASE WHEN result='sunk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM
(
    SELECT class, ship, result 
    FROM Classes c 
    LEFT JOIN Outcomes o 
    ON o.ship=c.class
UNION
    SELECT class, ship, result
    FROM Ships s 
    LEFT JOIN  Outcomes o 
    ON o.ship=s.class OR o.ship=s.name
)
AS res
GROUP BY class
```

Answer (score 2):

For each class this Query would return the number of ships that sunk so if no ship was sunk you will have a count of  0 instead of just showing the classes with count whose ships were sunk.

```
select class, count(ship) as Sunk_Count
from ships left outer join
(select outcomes.ship
from Outcomes
where result = 'Sunk') as result
on Ships.name = result.ship
group by class
```

here is how the output will look like

```
| ID | Class     | Sunk_Count |
| 1  | Kongo     |  1         | 
| 2  | Renown    |  0         |
| 3  | Revenge   |  0         |
| 4  | Tennessee |  0         |
| 5  | Yamato    |  0         |
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would vote up Kaczmarski as it was very close.  The answer that works has one additional line to pass the error check on second pass.

There needs to be a check to make sure the `ships.name` does not include a name which is also the class name.

An efficient database structure would include the Bismarck and all ships that were sunk in the outcomes table and also in the ships table. Or the ships table would contain none of the ships that were sunk.

This type of method must be used in a real world scenario in which a database is being modified by multiple users and a user has read access to a table that is being modified.

```
select class, sum(sunks) as sunks from(
    select class, sum(case result when 'sunk' then 1 else 0 end) as sunks 
    from classes c left join outcomes o on c.class = o.ship
where class not in (select name from ships) 
    group by class
    union all
    select class, sum(case result when 'sunk' then 1 else 0 end) as sunks
    from ships s left join outcomes o on s.name = o.ship
    group by class
)as x

group by class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer is hard to ready. Consider editing it and formatting it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient approach will be:

```
    select class, SUM(CASE WHEN result='sunk' 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 END) from
(
select class,ship as name,result from classes cc left outer join outcomes oo ON cc.class=oo.ship
union
select class,name,result from ships ss left outer join outcomes oo ON ss.name=oo.ship
) as ttt
group by class
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that is an old question, but I hope this could be helpful to anyone trying to figure out the answer for this exercise

The `outcomes` table can include ships that aren't included in the `ships` table.

With your queries you are including only ships from the `ships` table, You need to include some ships from the `outcomes` table. The question is, how to know to which class an outcome ship belongs to?.

A Few notes are given in the exercise

> 1. The Outcomes relation may contain ships not present in the Ships
>    relation.
> 2. A ship sunk can’t participate in later battles.
> 3. For historical reasons, lead ships are referred to as head ships in
>    many exercises.
> 4. A ship found in the Outcomes table but not in the Ships table is
>    still considered in the database. This is true even if it is sunk.

There is another statement for the `classes` table

> The ship whose name is assigned to a class is called a lead ship.

Based on that, you can get all the ships with the following query

```
 SELECT name FROM ships
 UNION
 SELECT ship FROM outcomes o
 JOIN classes c ON (o.ship = c.class)
```

If a ship is not present in the `ships` table but is present in the `outcomes` table, the only way to know it's class is to compare the name of the ship with all the classes, if there is a match, the ship is a lead ship.

This an example of a query that will give you the correct answer

```
WITH all_ships AS (
 SELECT name FROM ships
 UNION
 SELECT ship FROM outcomes o
 JOIN classes c ON (o.ship = c.class)
),
ships_sunked AS (
 SELECT name FROM all_ships
 JOIN outcomes o ON (o.ship = all_ships.name)
 WHERE o.result = 'sunk'
)
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(class, ss.name) FROM ships s
RIGHT JOIN ships_sunked ss ON (s.name = ss.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference in both queries. There can be difference if you remove group by and count from select. Because there can be more than one same ship names in different classes. Since you are using group by class then it doesn't make any difference in both queries. Both queries will return ships count per class.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good question to ask of your TA (Teaching Assistant?).  There may be "teaching" reasons why the answer in your book was used.

Although your query and the one from the book will produce the same result, your query cannot be easily modified to answer other questions about "classes".  For example, suppose the question changes to "How many ships were sunk for each country?".  A simple change to the "book query" makes that easy (using RBarryYoung's re-formatted code):

```
SELECT classes.country, COUNT(*)
FROM classes
INNER JOIN ships    ON classes.class = ships.class
INNER JOIN outcomes ON outcomes.ship = ships.name
WHERE  outcomes.result = 'sunk'
GROUP BY classes.country;
```

It may be a subtle point, but start queries with the table you are "most interested in" as the `FROM` clause and then join to other related tables as needed.  That at least makes your code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't list EACH classes only those where boat sunk
this is a bit better but seems still incorrect:

```
select class, sum(sunks) as sunks from(
    select class, sum(case result when 'sunk' then 1 else 0 end) as sunks 
    from classes c left join outcomes o on c.class = o.ship
    group by class
    union all
    select class, sum(case result when 'sunk' then 1 else 0 end) as sunks
    from ships s left join outcomes o on s.name = o.ship
    group by class
)as x
group by class
```